# How to know when to exit program when using multiple pipes?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, multiplexing

Let's say we have 3 pipes, 3 children that send data through them, 1 parent that reads this data (eg. printing some sent string). All the children are the same: they send data to pipe, let's say 4 times, and then they close their side of pipe and exit the program.

How can you know (in parent) that all the pipes have been closed?

1. When we're simply iterating through pipes, with some sleep time, and checking if there's some data to be read.
2. When we're using poll to read data (multiplexing).

(I'm not sure, but I think in the first case my program was returning with some pipe error, after all the write sides of pipes have been closed?)

I guess we could iterate through the write side of pipes and if all of them are -1?? (not sure to what value file descriptor is set when we close it, or if it's set at all, if not maybe we could set it by ourselves in child) then we can exit parent (data reading) program?

Comment: The child processes should exit as soon as they are done. The parent process needs to wait for all the children, both to reap them (with the `wait` family of functions) and to read the resulting data. It makes no sense to exit the parent process before it has received all the data and processed it. If the pipe-line is *independent* of the parent process, and the parent process doesn't need to read the resulting data, then it could just exit whenever it feels like, making the child processes orphans to be "adopted" by the init process.

Comment: As to know when the input from the last pipe has finished, why not read it in blocking mode? Then you can receive data as it's sent by the last child process, and `read` will return `0` when the pipe is closed by the child process exiting. Or if you want to do some other processing in parallel to the pipe, use `select` or `poll` or similar to check its read-end of the pipe to see when there is data to read (and it will be readable when the pipe is closed by the child-process).